# React: clicked link versus direct link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

This is probably something very simple, even simplistic, but... I have a React single page app created with `create-react-app`, a really simple app with only a few routes.

### **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import ArticleShow from './components/ArticleShow';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <section className="Header">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-4">
                <Link to="/" target="_self">
                  <span className="title">
                    <span className="title-feathers">Feathers</span>
                    <span className="title-4u">4U</span>
                  </span>
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="col-2  align-self-center" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <a href="https://feathersjs.com/" target="_new">
                  FeathersJS website
              </a>
              </div>
              <div className="col-2  align-self-center" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <Link to="/article/emerald-realm" target="_self">
                  Emerald Realm
              </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="col-2  align-self-center" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <Link to="/article/ed-de-almeida" target="_self">
                  Ed de Almeida
              </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="col-2  align-self-center" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                <Link to="/article/services">
                  Services
              </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="Contents">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-3">
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-header">
                    Articles
                </div>
                  <div className="card-body">
                    list
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-7">
                <div className="Article">
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
                    <Route path="/article/:file" component={ArticleShow} />
                  </Switch>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-2">
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-header">
                    Other sites
                </div>
                  <div className="card-body">
                    list
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-header">
                    Sponsors
                </div>
                  <div className="card-body">
                    list
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="Footer"></section>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

When I navigate to `http://myserver.com` and click one of the links at the top menu, say "Ed de Almeida" whose URL is `/article/ed-de-almeida` it picks correctly the markdown file `ed-de-almeida.md` in a certain directory, converts it to HTML and exhibits it in the central era of the page using the `ArticleShow` component. This is working fine.

But when I go directly to `http://myserver.com/article/ed-de-almeida` or refresh the page when it is correctly in this route, I get an error message:

> > `entry not found: /article/ed-de-almeida`.

What am I missing? Because I am sure I am missing something here!

## **EDIT**

### **ArticleShow.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const showdown  = require('showdown');
const converter = new showdown.Converter();

export default class ArticleShow extends React.Component {

    state = {
        text: { __html: "<div></div>" }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        let articleURL = '/articles/' + this.props.match.params.file + '.md';
        window.fetch(articleURL)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(txt => converter.makeHtml(txt))
        .then(html => this.setState({
            text: { __html: html }
        }))
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.state.text}></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `entry not found: /article/ed-de-almeida.` you sure it's `article` and not `articles` there?

Comment: Route is `<Route path="/article/:file" component={ArticleShow} />`, so it should be 'article', not 'articles'.

Comment: And, as I said in the question, when I click the link sending to `/article/ed-de-almeida` it works fine. Then the route is not the problem, I think.

Comment: In the question you use `articles` (plural), not `article` (singular), so which one is correct?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Call console.log in the constructor of ```ArticleShow``` to see if the component is being constructed properly.

Comment: Is your webserver configured for an SPA?

Comment: My mistake, @Clarity! The valid one is the one in the route, 'article' (singular). Thanks for pointing this. Already edited.

Comment: Do you have any more routes in your app other than / and /article/:file ?

Comment: Yes. The component is fine, @Anon. It runs smoothly when I use the link.

Comment: Not really, @laruiss. Do I need a special configuration? I tried the production version running a `npm run build` and point Web Server for Chrome to the `/build` directory. What configuration should I need?

Comment: I run it in my localhost and with some simple component and it work alright.
can you send the ArticleShow component? maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Sure @Omer. I edited the question with it.

Comment: In ArticleShow.js What about this line:
`let articleURL = '/articles/' + this.props.match.params.file + '.md';`
change articles to article. and I also so do not understand the dangerouslySetInnerHTML in the div.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida If you don't configure your webserver to always serve `index.html`, the webserver will thy to serve `http://myserver.com/article/ed-de-almeida/index.html` or something similar, while you want it to serve `http://myserver.com/index.html`

Comment: Let me try to explain this. The markdown files are inside a directory named **articles** at the root of the website. So, this line is realy `articles` (plural) because it ir referencing this directory, not a React route. As far as I know, the logic behind a SPA says it redirects 404 errors to index.html, but loads things when it finds them.

Comment: @laruiss I see. I do this when I create my own `webpack.config.js`, but I thought this would be done by `create-react-app`.

Comment: And besides, @laruiss, this does not explain why it works fine when I use the links and do NOT navigate directly to the URL.

Comment: @laruiss You were completely right! I found out in the advanced configurations of Web Server for Chrome the mod_rewrite option to redirect everything to /index.html and now it is working fine. Would you mind to post this as an answer, so I may accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You have to configure the webserver hosting your SPA to always serve your `index.html`, regardless of the path requested.

When you go to http://myserver.com, the default page is served by your web server, generally the same page attainable at `http://myserver.com/index.html`. When it is served, your JavaScript is parsed and run, and when you go to another route, it does not reload the page (hence **Single** Page App), but changes the url in the url/search field in your browser. That is all OK.

Now, when you got directly to a subroute, say `http://myserver.com/article/ed-de-almeida`, with default web server configuration, it will try to serve the page `http://myserver.com//article/ed-de-almeida/index.html`. This is not what you want, because the only real page you have is at `http://myserver.com/index.html`. So you have to configure your webserver to serve the page at `index.html` for every path requested from client, and let the SPA read the route and display the right components.

I will give you just 2 examples for 2 very common webserver : Apache HTTPd and nginx:

For Apache HTTPd:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomainname.tld
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Location /myreactapp >
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule . /mySPA/index.html [L]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or For nginx:

```
server {
    server_name mydomainname.tld;
    index index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /mySPA {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /mySPA/index.html;
    }
}
```